# How to ensure all class fields have been initialized before first use

Tags: c#, initialization

let's say I have a class that does some calculations. This set of calculations requires as an input a set of parameters.

```
public class Calculator
{
private CalculatorConfig _config;
public Calculator(CalculatorConfig config)
{
_config = config;
}

public Result Calculate(object obj){}
}
```

My CalculatorConfig class is very simple :

```
public class CalculatorConfig
{
      public double param1;
      public double param2;
      ...
}
```

and I initialize it very simply

```
var config = new CalculatorConfig();
config.param1 = val;
....
var calculator = new Calculator(config);
```

The dilema I have is that user of this class may forget to initialize some of the fields which may lead to weird behaviour. 
Solution that may make a sense would be to convert fields into properties and for each private field have an extra boolean that would hold the information whether the field was initialized.
I can also create a megaconstructor, that would have all the fields as arguments.

What approach would you choose in this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use another approach.

- Add another method (perhaps an internal method) called Check to your CalculatorConfig class.
- Call this method inside the execution of the Calculate method.
- In  the Check method verify each parameter and throw a custom
  exception is something is wrong

  ```
  public class CalculatorConfig 
  { 
    public double param1; 
    public double param2; 
    ... 
    internal void Check()
    {
         if(param1 == 0.0)
             throw new ArgumentException("Configuration error: param1 is not valid!");
         if(param2 == 0.0)
             throw new ArgumentException("Configuration error: param2 is not valid!");
         .... // other internal checks
    }
  } 


  public class Calculator 
  { 
      private CalculatorConfig _config; 
      public Calculator(CalculatorConfig config) 
      { 
          _config = config; 
      } 

      public Result Calculate(object obj)
      {
          // Throw ArgumentException if the configuration is not valid
          // Will be responsability of our caller to catch the exception
          _config.Check();

          // Do your calcs
          .....
      } 
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If all the parameters are absolutley required, then I'd go with the "mega constructor" option. its a more clean way to ensure everything is initialized, and you dont have to add extra boolean properties and deal with cases when something is NOT initialized. What will you do if one of your booleans will contain a false value? how can you enforce the user of your class to go back and add those values, except for with some kind of exception handling? The constructorw will simply ensure those things cant even happen at compile, rather than at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Set the default value in the declaration:

```
public class CalculatorConfig
{
      public double param1 = 1.0; // a default value chosen by you
      public double param2 = 2.0; // a default value chosen by you

}
```

Or a more OO solution: use properties instead of public fields, and then set default values when an instance is created:

```
public class CalculatorConfig
{
      public double param1 {get;set;}
      public double param2 {get;set;}

      public CalculatorConfig()
      {
          InitParams();
      }

      private void InitParams()
      {
          param1 = 1.0;
          param2 = 2.0;
      }
}
```

Comment: My personal experience from previous projects is that default values are evil. We had to deal with weird results that were created because somebody forgot to initialize some value and a default was used instead. I think that when somebody forgets to initialize a parameter deserves the worst punishment - exception.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your configuration parameters should be `readonly` (and arguably `private` but accessible via a property). Then, set warnings to be marked as errors. Then, when you fail to initialize one of these variables, you'll get a compile-time error

> The field `CalculatorConfig.param1` is never assigned to, and will always have its default value.

Now you've caught the issue at compile time.

Comment: Does this approche work if we are designing classes that will be used in different envirenement somthing as a library or a framework ?

Comment: I don't see why that would matter.

Comment: i think that 'set warnings to be marked as errors' will be valid only if you are the client of your propre API, what will happen if you code if distribute as a dll in ordre to be used with different clients.