# Ensure that all NEW instances of a class implements ALL fields or properties

Tags: c#

Lets say I have a class

```
class Car
{
    string color;
    bool fourDoor;
    int numberOfTires;
}
```

And I create a new instance

```
Car myCar = new Car();
myCar.color = "green";
myCar.fourDoor = true;
```

I haven't assigned anything to `numberOfTires` so how do I make it throw a compile warning/error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That isn't something  supported by the  compiler as it is not required to assign something to all properties. You *could* write an analyzer for it, but in non-trivial cases it will quickly become "halting problem" complex.

Note that  if `Car` was a `struct` then that *can* be checked via a very specific syntax (only if you don't initialize the value first), but: that  is so nuanced that  it won't help you, and it wouldn't  be good advice (and that is before we discuss the issue of mutable structs).

In your case, your best bet would be to use the constructor  to declare what things you **require**. Then it becomes:

```
 Car myCar = new Car(color: "green", fourDoor: true, numberOfTires: 42);
```

My explicit usag of parameter names is purely for visibility; it would work just  as well as:

```
Car myCar = new Car("green", true, 42);
```

This would  map to something like:

```
class Car
{
    public string Color {get;}
    public bool FourDoor {get;}
    public int NumberOfTires {get;}
    public Car(string color, bool fourDoor, int numberOfTires)
    {
        Color = color;
        FourDoor = fourDoor;
        NumberOfTires = numberOfTires;
    }
}
```

Comment: This fundamentally changed how I look at classes, its one of those things that just "clicked" like ok now I get it. The code examples really helped a lot. Thanks!

Comment: The only other thing I need clarification on, does the constructor take place of using a setter in the property?

Comment: @Skedge The constructor is only ever called when you're declaring a new instance of that class. It's never called again.

Answer (score 4):

For such case, you should use constructor with arguments. Take a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6sa6h87.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

Jason gives a good option for your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10720455/3836632

"I think that your configuration parameters should be `readonly` (and arguably `private` but accessible via a property). Then, set warnings to be marked as errors. Then, when you fail to initialize one of these variables, you'll get a compile-time error

> The field `CalculatorConfig.param1` is never assigned to, and will always have its default value.

Now you've caught the issue at compile time."

Answer (score 0):

- List item

You can set the properties that need to initialised in the argument of the constructor. This way u can force the user to pass value during the object creation.

public class Car
    {
        public Car(string color, bool fourDoor, int numberOfTires)
        {
            this.Color = color;
            this.FourDoor = fourDoor;
            this.NumberOfTires = numberOfTires;
        }

```
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public bool FourDoor { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfTires { get; set; }
}
```